# Need publish_actions permission in facebook api v2.4

Tags: facebook

i'm realy stucking in request to review in app creation facebook api. Please find the attached screenshot.

I have created new app with v2.4 in facebook api. For our application we need below four permission like publish_actions, manage_pages,user_likes,read_stream.

I have entered notes for all items. But in publish_actions it showing error like below.

Can anyone tell what i need to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can send `publish_actions` to review, you need to make sure it works in your App. Just do a call that involves `publish_actions` from your App with your App Admin/Developer account.

Btw, you may want to read the changelog about `read_stream`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

Comment: Hi Luschn,  Thanks for your reply. It's worked fine.

Comment: you´re welcome. please don´t forgot to accept my answer :)